# My SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo returns ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS for certain devices (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, drivers, setupapi

I am trying to fetch power data for my devices(cm_power_data_s). 
I am using the `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` API to do so.
 While this works fine for some devices, it doesn't work for others.
 The data returned by `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` is `null`, and without this, I can't use `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`.  
I tried manually filling `sp_devinfo_data` by making a `wmi` query to get the class `GUID`, but `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` doesn't return the buffer size with it (same as passing null data). 
Can someone please help? 
Here's my code:

```
uint SPDRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA = 0x0000001E;
        int proptype;
        int size;
        //int D3, D2, D1, D3wake, cap = 0;
        DEVPROPKEY key = DEVPROPKEY.DEVPKEY_Device_PowerData;

        IntPtr hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(IntPtr.Zero, DevID, IntPtr.Zero, DIGCF.DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | DIGCF.DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF.DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
        if (hDevInfo == (IntPtr)INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("invalidhandle");
        }
        SP_DEVINFO_DATA data = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
        data.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(data);

        SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, 0, ref data); // This data is empty for some devices
       // SetupDiGetSelectedDevice(hDevInfo, ref data);
        int aa = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        bool b = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, ref data, SPDRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA, out proptype, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out size);
        int a = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (size == 0)
        {
                          return "";
         //   throw new ArgumentNullException("Power Data cannot be fetched");
        }

        IntPtr buffer1 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, ref data, SPDRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA, out proptype, buffer1, size, out size))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        }
```

Comment: You aren't checking the return value of functions such as `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` to see if they succeeded or failed. Which means you miss your chance to check the last error code to see *why* they failed.

Comment: I am checking the error with int aa = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
and it fails with error 259 which is ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS.

Comment: So maybe there are no devices in the specified set.

Comment: Actually, no. I am passing it with index 0 which should give me the device's data for which I have obtained a specific handle(hDevInfo) by passing its DeviceInstanceID. 

I have also tried SetupDiGetSelectedDevice(hDevInfo, ref data) to get the data and this is for the selected device for which we have the hDevInfo. This also returns error - no_more items and data is null. But I can clearly go to device manager and see the class GUID, power data etc.

This doesn't happen for all devices, and I have still not observed any pattern in the devices that fail with this api.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've long since moved on since this question is from 18 months ago, but I just hit exactly this same problem.  My googling brought me to your thread.  Then I figured it out.  So in case anyone else ever hits this, the problem is the flags that you supplied to SetupDiGetClassDevs.

You should have just given it the DIGCF_PRESENT flag.  With all the flags you supplied you get back info for devices that aren't even there, leading to exactly the subsequent error you and I both got.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I attempted to enable/disable netowrk interface, and used Setup API to get the index of the device that must be passed to SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(). I didn't cache the index, but got ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS arised randomly when dealing with the Setup API funcions.

The problem in behind was that the "list of network adapters" changed in between, f.ex., the "Microsoft ISATAP adapter" disappeared from the list (I also could see that it is hidden in device manager).

In my case using DIGCF_PROFILE **instead of** DIGCF_PRESENT worked for me.